# Simplest way of accomplishing well-spaced layout of arrows (node / edge graphs).

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science, math-software, computational-geometry

Here is a picture of 3 arrows that I manually set to bezier and manually dragged the control points of to make them look okay as parallel arrows will by-default collide and overlap each other.  However, I need a simple geometric method for accomplishing the same thing automatically.

[image: BananaCats spaced arrow picture.]

Also when I move a node, I'd like the arrows to follow the line between the center points of the two nodes, or in other words all control points will proportionally move along with node movement.

Thus layout is good-looking and automatically done for the user.

I prefer not to use spring physics because I don't need and do not desire the arrows to "oscillate / bounce" in place.

> Thus, my **question is** *what is the easiest method to accomplish the above?*  Also the algorithm must know when to not be used, i.e. if the graph is a 3D cubic, as in:

[image: 3D cubic commutative diagram]

then the algorithm should not space the crossing arrows, but just let them cross.  So I guess, if the arrows aren't parallel and they collide, then maybe check if small bends will uncross them (?) not sure here!

I should be able to call a scene-level method that updates all arrows to a well-spaced final position.

The nodes will not be auto-positioned, I'm just looking at the arrows for now.  For the nodes, I might do "allign to grid" or something...

Comment: What exactly is your problem with a spring-aligned algorithm? (afaik) these are the standard tool for doing exactly what you want, that is, nicely spacing edges in a graph.

Comment: Have a look at the [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/) home page where they point to theory and papers. This is a complex and non-trivial task.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts hence the usage of the word "simple" here.  I'm not looking to replace GraphViz.  After all, small commutative diagrams are typically a proper subclass of general, directed multi-graphs.  I will post a solution once I'm done coding it using Coulomb's static electric inverse-square law.  I also specified just doing this for parallel arrows, which makes determining the set of arrows to position and how they should be positioned much simpler.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor thanks.  I might use Coulomb's law for this, but maybe not springs.